# Draw color using finger on custom view in android

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I am working in a app, in which I have to develop ALPHABETS, one alphabet in one screen, and so on.

when some one move finger over the Alphabet, it draws color over the alphabet.

The color is visible only over the alphabet, not over the background of the screen.
 I wish i can post screenshot. please refer this app for more information-

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kr.co.smartstudy.phonicsiap_android_googlemarket

in this app we draw alphabet. Same I want to draw.
I have no idea how to develop it, if anyone have some idea in it, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering to my question. 
My requirement was to draw only over the ALPHABETS. I achieved this functionality by creating custom view with override draw method.

Below is my code snippet:

```
public class DrawingView extends  View{

private final Paint mAlphaPaint;
private final Paint clearPaint;

public int width;
public int height;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas,mCanvasWhite;
private Path mPath,alphaPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
Context context;
private Paint circlePaint;
private Path circlePath;
private Bitmap mBitmapWhite;

public DrawingView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    context = c;
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePath = new Path();
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    circlePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(110f);


    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics =  getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    alphaPath = new Path();
    alphaPath.moveTo(width*.5f, height*0.1f);
    alphaPath.lineTo(100, 100);
    alphaPath.lineTo(100, 150);
    alphaPath.lineTo(width/2, height/2);
    alphaPath.lineTo(100, height - 300);

    mAlphaPaint = new Paint();
    mAlphaPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mAlphaPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mAlphaPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mAlphaPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mAlphaPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mAlphaPaint.setStrokeWidth(220f);

     clearPaint = new Paint();
    clearPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    clearPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    clearPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    clearPaint.setStrokeWidth(220f);
    clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    clearPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.GREEN);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
     mCanvas.drawPath(alphaPath, clearPaint);
    mBitmapWhite = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmapWhite.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);
    mCanvasWhite = new Canvas(mBitmapWhite);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapWhite,0,0,circlePaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, circlePaint);
    mCanvasWhite.drawPath(mPath, circlePaint);


}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    circlePath.reset();
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvasWhite.drawPath(mPath, circlePaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    Log.d("onTouchEvent",x+","+y);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Add this view in your layout. In it we can draw on line not on whole surface.
I hope it will help you.